# Crawling webpage with scrapy

Tags: python, xpath, scrapy

Been reading up on Scrapy. My python skills are weak but i usually am able to build something on trial and error and determination...

I'm able to run trough my project site and scrape 'structured' product data. 
The problem occurs with a table that has different rows and values per page. 
Beneath an example, I can get the name and price of the product.

The problem is with the table underneath, products have different specifications and different amount of rows but always 2 columns. I'm trying to loop trough by counting the `<tr>` and for each get the first `<td>` as a label and the second `<td>` as the corresponding value. Then append it with the other page data to create 1 entry.

In the end i'd like to yield Name: name, Price:price, Label X : Value X, label y : value y

```
<div>name</div>
<div>price</div>

<table>
    <tr><td>LABEL X</td><td>VALUE X</td></tr>
    <tr><td>LABEL Y</td><td>VALUE Y</td></tr>
    <tr><td>LABEL Z</td><td>VALUE Z</td></tr>

    Could be anywhere from 2 to 6 rows

</table>
```

Any help would be much appreciated, or if someone could point me to an example.

EDIT >>>>

The HTML code

```
<table class="table table-striped">                     
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Name:</b></td>
            <td>Car</td>
        </tr>                           
        <tr>
            <td><b>Brand:</b></td>
            <td itemprop="brand">Merc</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Size:</b></td>
            <td>30 XL</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Color:</b></td>
            <td>white</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><b>Stock</b></td>
            <td>20</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Could you include a link to the page you are crawling, and your current scrapy code?

Answer (score 0):

You should have posted some Scrapy code to help us out.

Anyways, here is the code you can use to parse your HTML.

```
for row in response.css('table > tr'):

    data = {}
    data['name'] = row.css("td:nth-child(1) b::text").extract()[0]
    data['value'] = row.css("td:nth-child(2)::text").extract()[0]

    yield MyItem(name = data['name'], value = data['value'])
```

**PS:**
Do not use `tbody` in selectors on xpaths, `tbody` is added by modern browsers, its not included in original response.

See here: https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.14/topics/firefox.html

> Firefox, in particular, is known for adding  elements to tables. Scrapy, on the other hand, does not modify the original page HTML, so you won’t be able to extract any data if you use